# Please vote on tag synonyms.

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

If you see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page, there are many "pending" tag synonyms.  I' have noticed that very few people bother voting on tag synonyms.  This post is like a request for people to  vote on tag synonyms.

If you have at least 5 reputation on a particular tag (you can see how much reputation you have on a particular tag [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23119?tab=tags), replacing "23119" with   your own    user id.),              please consider voting on tag synonyms.

In addition, if you also have 2500 reputation, consider proposing tag synonyms (this is a little hard, because  the synonym needs to exist first.).

Answer (score 3):

You've got the requirements wrong, they're slightly stricter. <s>Firstly, 2.5k rep is needed for voting, too.</s> In addition, it's a *score* (upvotes-downvotes) of five from answers.

<s>As a result we usually (depends on the tag) don't have the requisite number of people to get synonyms  by community voting</s>.

The syn page isn't too visible and there's not much of a chance to discuss. Instead, the synonyms usually get proposed on the other meta thread, and mod approved if there seems to be consensus. Yes, there are a couple of upvoted ones there that need to be looked at, I'll do that soon.

FWIW I don't like the abbreviation-synonyms you proposed there as much, I don't see a need for them. The particle->particle-physics is an iffy one too; the word has a broader meaning. But the tags are usually used to mean the same thing.

Comment: 1. No; I could vote on tag synonyms at before I got 2000 rep; 2.   By "5 rep on the     tag", I meant the score.  3. There are a couple of users (maaaaaany) who can vote  on many of the  proposed synonyms. 4. Well, [tag:qft] is a synonym for [tag:quantum-field-theory],. 5.

Comment: @dim (1-3) Ah, I misinterpreted the priv page, m y bad. Still, the meta post is usually better. But it's good to encourage the community to use the built in mechanism. (4) That's probably because it was being used that way.  I haven't seen  anyone tagging their question with GR.

Comment: It's much easier to tag  as "gr" as opposed to "general-relativity".

Comment: I think it's a lot easier to type "gen" and then tab your way to the correct tag. The tagging mechanism is helpful enough that we can include some redundancy into the tag names to make them more human-readable.